# Solving $\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{1}{y}=c$ for $y$ is giving a wrong answer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a simple equation where I want to solve for $y$ but I am getting wrong answer using my steps with some slight sign changes. I know I am making a silly mistake somewhere but its frustrating that I can't find it. Kindly take a look.

***NOTE:** I know I can see steps in Symbolab but I want to know where I am wrong in my steps. Thanks*

$$\cfrac{x^4}{4}+\cfrac{1}{y} = c $$

The answer should be:

$$y=-\cfrac{4}{x^4-4c}$$

but, as shown below, I am getting:

$$y = \frac{4}{4c-x^4}$$

[image]

[image]

Comment: They are the same

Comment: My bad. Silly me. I overlooked. Did try to factor sign but got confused don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is:

$$y=\frac{4}{4c-x^4}$$

Let's factor out a negative sign from the denominator to get:

$$y=-\frac{4}{x^4-4c}$$

which is exactly what Symbolab has. Your solution is identical.

Comment: oh yeah. I did factor the sign from denominator but then I thought to my self that this sign is only for denominator which might not be the same. Guess I'm getting a little rusty. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

They are equal, note that $-(x^4-4c)=4c-x^4$.

You just write in different form.

Comment: Thanks. How could I have missed that.